can't upgrade from 23.04 to 24.04
In the update program, if I open it, it tells me to upgrade to 23.10, but now 24.04 is released, and I want to upgrade from 23.04 to 24.04.


Ubuntu 23.04 is a non-LTS that has one release-upgrade path, to the next release. You cannot skip on a non-LTS release; you can only skip from a LTS to the next LTS release.  Ubuntu 22.10, 23.04, 23.10 & 24.04 are on the same two year development cycle; you must upgrade through all OR upgrade from the 22.04 LTS (prior two year cycle) to 24.04 LTS.

This is the intended behavior. We have not tested 23.04 to 24.04 direct migration. It might work, it might not. You are asking to do that testing, and to solve any discovered problems yourself. If you don't want to be a tester, then follow the recommended 23.04 to 23.10 path.

It may be easier to perform a fresh installation of 24.04
